# How do I transform unique row combinations into sorted tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['bar',0],['restaurant',0],
...                    ['bar',0],
...                    ['movie',1],['bar',1],['restaurant',1],
...                    ['bar',2],['restaurant',2],['movie',2]]
...                    ,columns=['place','ID'])
>>> df
        place  ID
0         bar   0
1  restaurant   0
2         bar   0
3       movie   1
4         bar   1
5  restaurant   1
6         bar   2
7  restaurant   2
8       movie   2
```

I would like to group by the ID and get the unique combinations of places, in order, with repeats allowed. If I do this:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['place'].unique().apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).reset_index()
   ID                     place
0   0         (bar, restaurant)
1   1  (bar, movie, restaurant)
2   2  (bar, movie, restaurant)
```

It is almost correct, but I want repeats allowed:

```
                      place  ID
0    (bar, bar, restaurant)   0
1  (bar, movie, restaurant)   1
2  (bar, movie, restaurant)   2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use groupby with `as_index=False` without `unique`.
It is also faster if we order first instead of ordering each group.

```
new_df = (df.sort_values('place')
            .groupby('ID',as_index=False)[['place']]
            .agg(tuple))
print(new_df)

   ID                     place
0   0    (bar, bar, restaurant)
1   1  (bar, movie, restaurant)
2   2  (bar, movie, restaurant)
```

Or :

```
(df.sort_values('place')
   .groupby('ID')['place']
   .apply(tuple)
   .reset_index()
)
```